# undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string in Boost on Travis CI

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, travis-ci

I am trying to get a C+++ project which uses Boost on GitHub to compile correctly on Travis CI.

First I tried the packages and PPAs on ubuntu, but they were too old(I need at least Boost 1.61).

I got it to work only if I compiled Boost on Travis CI(download, compile), but, unfortunately, the compile time is big (11-18 mins) and the log file is just huge.

Thinking how to get over this issues, I thinked about compiling boost on my machine, zipping, uploading to some web server and just downloading and copying on /usr/local/[include/lib] the corresponding files.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/kRPp9A0p) is the compiler I used on my machine. I compiled boost using

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/andrei/boostabc
/usr/bin/time ./b2 install link=static
```

[Here](https://github.com/xTachyon/TravisLibTest/blob/master/.travis.yml) is the travis file (and repository). In comments is the way I did it with compiling boost.

The problem is that I get a lot of errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::dir_itr_first(void*&, void*&, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::filesystem::file_status&, boost::filesystem::file_status&) [clone .isra.46] [clone .constprop.56]':
operations.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

I googled this [errors](https://travis-ci.org/xTachyon/TravisLibTest/builds/177441695) and I found there might be a misconfig about some C++11 ABI and a macro. I didn't understand very well the explanation and I do not have any idea how to get it working.

I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction of solving this.

Comment: Use Travis CI for boost as well, but make it a separate project, which will fetch the sources, build boost, package it, and upload to repository (e.g. "some webserver"). I use similar process in my CI system, except i use an artifact repository and dependency management to tie things together. Would go crazy if every commit trigged builds of all the dependencies used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try the adding -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 to the command line used to compile it, and see if this gets rid of the problem.

I think its quite possible that one or other of the g++/gcc you are calling is not version 6 ... otherwise this would be set to 1 by default iirc.

[This is documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/using_dual_abi.html)

Comment: I am sure that I built boost on my machine with gcc 6.2(I have folders like bin.v2/libs/atomic/gcc-6.2.0. Travis's Cmake confirms that I'm using 6.2.0(The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0). I don't know where else something would use another version of gcc. I'll try to compile with that flag (like b2 install -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 ?).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ISO C++ doesn't support it, according to the result of linker.You can try compile with `g++ yourfiles.cc -std=c++11`